# Things to lookout for, when adding a button to the properties menu of a webpart and even handler not executing

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property

Ive built a custom Web Part properties menu, using a class which extends the Editor Part following this [tutorial](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2014/05/custom-webpart-editor/) . I created a button with the following code

```
        this.testButton = new Button();
        this.testButton.Width = new Unit("100%");
        this.testButton.Text = "Get Parameters";
        this.testButton.ID = "testButton";
        this.testButton.Click += new EventHandler(testButton_Click);

        this.pnlMain.Controls.Add(this.testButton);
```

yet the buttons server side code (testButton_Click) is not being executed, never. Googiling did not help much until now.

Comment: have you tried debugging and testing if the click is being fired?

Comment: yes tried, not luck at all, i arranged some literal code that i was inputting inside the CreateChildControls and seems the problem was coming form elsewhere

Comment: maybe it helps when you create the control again and just add the button to the ascx page